# My wifi is hard blocked in Ubuntu, how to bring it up despite rfkill

Tags: wifi, network-interface, networkmanager, iwlwifi

My wifi is not working in Ubuntu 16.04, it is hard blocked, but there is no any physical switch that i can turn it on.

My PC is G34 XOTIC PC

This question was asked and answered more than 50 times all over the Internet space, but non of the solutions worked. The most common answer to this is blacklisting 'wmi' inside the blacklist.conf file, still this was not helpful  Here are some useful info about my device:

```
##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8]
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1849:15b8]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
Kernel driver in use: igb

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet    K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:1007  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

 ##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                385024  0
mac80211              782336  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               249856  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              614400  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    24576  0
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Use `sudo rfkill unblock all` command.

Comment: What make/model of computer?

Comment: My PC is G34 XOTIC PC

Comment: Is the appropriate firmware file available for the WiFi chip driver? If the firmware is missing, the chip will not function and may report a hardware-RFkill state as a result. The chip is apparently Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265, so the firmware file would be `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode`. [Download from Linux Wireless Wiki here.](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz)

Answer (score 1):

If you read [net/rfkill/core.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/rfkill/core.c):rfkill_set_block() you can see that "hard" blocks are set from outside of Linux's control. Something like a key sequence, a BIOS setting, or a physical switch.

Let's look up the mainboard manual and see which of those posibilities are most likely. This  [promotional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSvA7__ABw4) says the mainboard is a "Asus Z170i Pro Gaming". The [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170I_PRO_GAMING/E10725_Z170I-PRO_GAMING_UM_WEB.pdf) says there are BIOS toggles for both WiFi and Bluetooth operation. Turn both on and power cycle.

My quick reading of the mainboard's jumpers shows no physical switch, although you might wish to read more closely. There are WiFi antenna connectors on the rear panel, and you should make sure the WiFi antennas are properly homed into those connectors -- many systems turn off the RF system if no antenna is present.

You can reset the firmware settings, see the manual for the jumper.

Answer (score 0):

On a Dell Vostro 3550 laptop, hold the "**Fn**" key and type the "**F2**" key to toggle Wi-Fi on and off.

Comment: I dont have any hard ware switch, niether do I have Fn key. My PC is G34 XOTIC PC